# How can I hightlight active navbar paragraph

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is react-component - navbar:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <a data-id="first" href="/">/</a>
      <a data-id="second" href="/link">/link</a>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

```html
<Navbar active="second" />
```

How, depending on `props.active`, can you select the active element?

In plain js I would create an object of links and using a loop generate the navbar:

```js
const objOfLinks = {
  "1": {
    text: "some text",
    href: "/"
  },
  "2": {
    text: "some text",
    href: "/link"
  }
}

function nav(obj, active = "1") {
  let nav = document.createElement('nav');
  for (item in obj) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = obj[item].text;
    a.href = obj[item].href;
    if (item == active) {
      a.style.color = 'red';
    }
    nav.appendChild(a);
  }

  return nav;
}

document.querySelector('div').appendChild(nav(objOfLinks, 2));
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Using `map` as you mention in your example is a better way, check my answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple answer should give you an idea, also using `map` with an array of links.

```js
const linkArr = [
  {
    text: "some text",
    href: "/"
  },
  {
    text: "some text",
    href: "/link"
  }
]

function Navbar({active}) {
 const activeStyle = {color:"red"}
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      {linkArr.map((link,i) =>(
        <a href={link.href} style={active === i ? activeStyle : {}}>{link.text}</a>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Navbar active={1} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add class based on props like this:

```
function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <a
        data-id="first"
        className={props.active === "first" ? "active" : ""}
        href="/"
      >
        First
      </a>
      <a
        data-id="second"
        className={props.active === "second" ? "active" : ""}
        href="/link"
      >
        Second
      </a>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-forest-5edu1?file=/src/App.js:51-428